# Is it ok to use sleep() in a loop to be nice?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, sleep

I couldn't describe the question better.

this is from redis-py github page.

```
>>> while True:
>>>     message = p.get_message()
>>>     if message:
>>>         # do something with the message
>>>     time.sleep(0.001)  # be nice to the system :)
```

I thought this style of coding (sleep in a loop) isn't so great, but this library leaves me no other option than to use this style. (at least they suggest it this way)

Is this ok to live with?

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

Comment: If `p.get_message()` blocks, there's no need to sleep. You'll be nice while you're waiting for a message.

Comment: get_message doesn't block

Comment: If that's all you need to do, then I suggest using `listen()` to block until a message comes in. And if you're building a complex application it would be still better to have a DB thread that uses `listen()` and handles things without sleeping. If you're making a quick 'n' dirty script then `sleep()` is fine.

Comment: There are alternatives listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's OK, **if the library does not offer an alternative**.

- Busy waiting *without sleeping* is very evil, because it uses up a huge amount of CPU time.
- Busy waiting *with sleeping* is not very elegant, but the CPU load is almost always negligible.

Comment: Please put "if the library does not offer an alternative" in quadruple bold, though.

Comment: Then why only 1ms why not 100ms ? I think that will save more CPU

Comment: There's also the third possibility: sleeping even though you're not busy waiting, which is marginally evil. Some new programmers will do `print("processing..."); sleep(3)` so it makes it look like their program is thinking really hard ;-)

Comment: Incidentally, the library **does** offer an alternative: the `listen` method will block.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: Because this is micro-optimization. Even 1ms is negligible on a GHz processor.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: Done. :-) Good catch with the `listen` method! I'll keep my answer here, though, as a general answer to the question in the title.

Comment: well listen() is not an alternative in a sense that you can't stop waiting for the event as you could with get_message() (even with ugly sleep() ). anyway, point of my question is fully answered by Heinzi's

Comment: 1ms is OK, the purpose of the sleep is not so much to actually sleep but to give-up the CPU time-slice, then go to the back of the queue and allow others to execute.

Answer (score 5):

No need to sleep in this case! [The docstring for `get_message`](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/c4e2f56dbf6e04a23e6a346ac54278cfbf4035e1/redis/client.py#L2233) says that you can specify a `timeout` parameter and the function will wait for `timeout` seconds before returning.

```
while True:
    message = p.get_message(timeout=0.1) # or however long you'd want to wait
    if message:
        # do something with the message
```

If you do not insist on using `get_message`, there is the [`listen` method](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/9da5664e9d4b1f95c9c4e01db765996fdbc4dba6/redis/client.py#L2212), which will block until the next message arrives. Actually, its usage is explained on the [project's Github page](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) right below the code example you've posted. It's just used like any other iterator:

```
for message in p.listen():
    # do something with the message
```

Comment: Just above `get_message` is the `listen` method, which blocks, and is an even better solution in this case.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Yes, you're right, tanks! (haven't used this library before, was just doing a quick search in the code.) I'll update my anser.

Comment: timeout parameter is in master branch but not in it's latest stable 2.10.3 (pip install) .. good to know!

Comment: timeout parameter is buggy atm. just fyi